# Lombok @Data generates no empty constructor whith no final fields

Tags: java, constructor, lombok

The Lombok annotation `@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates an empty constructor when no final fields are present, this code compiles without error:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LombokTest {

    public LombokTest(String a) {
        // to avoid creation of the default constructor by the Java compiler
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LombokTest();
    }
}
```

According to the Lombok documentation, the annotation `@Data` should also generate a `RequiredArgsConstructor`, but in the following code

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class LombokTest {

    public LombokTest(String a) {
        // to avoid creation of the default constructor by the Java compiler
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LombokTest();
    }
}
```

the new LombokTest() in the main method causes an error because the no-arg constructor is undefined.

Is this a bug in Lombok?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not really a bug in Lombok.
If you put the @Data on class, the empty constructor will be generated only if you have not any other constructor.

It's the same if you put @AllArgsConstructor and @Data on the class: the empty constructor will not be generated since the constructor with all arguments will be generated.

You can add @NoArgsConstructor to generate the empty constructor.

Comment: The default empty constructor will be generated by the Java compiler, not by Lombok. The Lombok documentation states: `@Data is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor together...` Therefore it should always generate a RequiredArgsConstructor, which is an empty constructor in this case.

Comment: Yes emtpy construtor will be generated by Java but only if you don't have any other constructor: lombok stick to this principle...

Comment: That's why I added an explicit constructor in both cases so we can concentrate on the Lombok behavior.

Comment: I don't have any other constructor, but it still complains that - `its not public and cannot be accessed out the package`. But after adding `@NoArgsConstructor`, the error goes away. Any reason for this?